# trying to convert date type to Time type in php to insert into a column of type time

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

this has held me up all day i have a column called hours where i add up hours (not clock time) I have a method which takes one date from the other (starttime -endtime) but when i try and update a entry with the hours it wont work bellow is my code.

```
private function calculatedifference($starttime,$endtime) // delete checkin time from     checkouttime
{

    $diff=  abs(strtotime($starttime) - strtotime($endtime));
    return  date("H:i:s",$diff);

}
```

i then proceed to try and update a row based on a users email and their starttime. but it doesnt work? below are my methods in my model to update the entry and the line of code i use to call that method.

```
function update_daily_row($email,$date,$data)//update existing row.
  {


$this->db->where('email', $email);
$this->db->where('starttime', time($date));
    $this->db->update('dailyinfo', $data); 


  }
```

here is where i call the method.

```
$hours=$this->calculatedifference(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",
 $this->session->userdata
('last_activity')),date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$data =array("hours"=>$hours,"endtime"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$this->dbaccess->update_daily_row
($this->cdata['email'],
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",
$this->session->userdata('last_activity')),$data);
```

any help would be appreciated as ive actually gone blind from looking at the thing

update: so i checked the query using this  command

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

returned the query the email address missing? that means active record probably doesnt like the format of the email address. is there anyway around this?

my query returns after using this method as

```
UPDATE `dailyinfo` SET `endtime` = '2013-10-02 21:14:02',
 `hours` = '00:00:03' WHERE `email` = ''AND `starttime` = '2013-10-02 21:13:59'
```

so the email is always blank. not sure how to fix this???

Comment: so it seems that active record dosent like my email address being passed. got to figure out a way around this. any help with this?

Comment: if you do `var_dump($this->cdata['email'])` before the dbaccess line do you see the email?

Comment: $this->dbaccess->update_daily_row($this->cdata['email'],
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$this->session->userdata('last_activity')),$data); the $this->cdata['email'] part of the query doesnt work as its got a "."  in it. the email doest appear but when i hardcode it the query works fine